# SQL Compact Server 3.5 orderby statement - windows phone

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to output all the information from the database. From my code, it works. But it actually output everything. I would like to order it by dates. How can I do that. Below is my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }

        using (DatabaseContext c = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            //c.CreateIfNotExists();
            if (!c.DatabaseExists())
            {
                c.CreateDatabase();
            }

            c.LogDebug = true;
            //output todolist data from database

            try
            {
                MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoList.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Source + ":" + exc.Message);
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: c.ToDoList.OrderBy(l => l.<YourDateProperty>).ToList();

Comment: c.ToDoList.OrderBy(l => l.Date).ToList(); This is what i state to my code. It didnt work. It crashed

Comment: I don't see `OrderBy` in the code mentioned above. I don't see any information about crash.

Comment: what do you mean by didnt see OrderBy in the code. How can i do that? From the break point, MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = null

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, your code is working! Thanks! maybe you could recreate a post to this question so I could accept it as an answer. But what I am trying to search for is to order it by Today's date. as in like Date.Now in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = c.ToDoList.OrderBy(datefilter => datefilter.Date).ToList();
```

To Order by today's current date and time,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var result1 =  c.ToDoList().Where(test => test.Date.Date == today).OrderByDescending(t=>t.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to order it by the current date as in today

Comment: I dont have any extension method for TimeOfDay or even Time in my ToDoLIst

Comment: i modified it, Date is the property you have used for your date

Comment: CollectionList doesnot exist in my current context.

Comment: Honestly i dont get what it means

Comment: Where do you have the data now?

Comment: From my database table called ToDoList

Comment: Changed the answer please check.

Comment: It said that ToDoList() is a type. it should be used like a variable

Comment: DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                    var result1 = ToDoList().Where(test => test.Date.Date == today).OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).ToList();
                    MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = result1;

Comment: you have missed your datacontext, check properly

Comment: c.ToDoList.Where(test => test.Date.Date == today).OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).ToList(); This is what i have changed. and it states that the Date im missing a using directive?

Comment: Honestly im first time in Windows Phone field. Thats why im trying it out. Sorry if it trouble you. Ill try to figure that solution out first.

Comment: Just kidding!  try your best!